Content Security Policy is blocking outgoing requests
I will use example.com, but my domain is publicly accessible URL.
I have meta element set in my HTML:
<meta http-equiv="content-security-policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; connect-src 'self' https://example.com;">

Note the connect-src 'self' https://example.com;".
However, if I try to request the URL with fetch like below:
const response = await fetch(baseUrl + generatePath, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer 1234',
        'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
})

The request is not even made, and i can see the error in browser's console:

Refused to connect to 'https://example.com/api/generate' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Which is extremely strange, because I have it set. What's more strange is that when I run it on locahost:5173, the request is made, on port 3000 it fails.
The same happens when I deploy it to Azure and access it from different domain.
I just don't know how to solve it. I have seen similair questions about HTTP request headers, but there is no request made at all.
It happens on Chrome and Opera browsers.

The key to this problem was that behind localhost:3000 as well as in Azure, there was docker image with NGINX proxying requests.
So I have looked into the configuration I had and it turned out I had the setting that conflicted with the ones set in HTML.
Part of NGINX configuration:
location / {
  root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index  index.html index.htm;
  try_files $uri /index.html =404;
  # This must be removed.  
  add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:;";
}

